# Azure DevOps - System.Security.Cryptography related errors when running build task in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, uwp, msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2020

In DevOps Server 2020 I've got a pipeline that has a MSBuild step that is failing for my UWP app. When attempting to build, I receive errors such as the following:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.11-rel-30601-02\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): Error : Type 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms' from assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'Signature.GetContentPackage(SignedCms, X509IncludeOption)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.

##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.11-rel-30601-02\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): Error : Type 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignerInfo' from assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'Pkcs7.ValidateOverride(SignatureDataProperties, SignatureValidationProperties)'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.

##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.11-rel-30601-02\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): Error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.11-rel-30601-02\tools\x64\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"O:\Agent1\_work\211\s\MyApp\MyApp.UWP\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\MyApp.UWP.rsp"' returned exit code 1
```

I can successfully build the app if I execute the build manually via MSBuild in the command-line (using the same arguments as DevOps) but when DevOps attempts to do so, it gets those errors. I've tried searching for these errors but haven't had much luck finding anyone that has encountered this before. Hoping that someone here can offer some tips on what this might be, and how we can get this across the line. Thanks!